# How to represent nested JSON in Angular Classes?

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, parsing

I get this JSON from a server:

```
"Body": {
    "ErrorsContent": {
        "FunctionalError": [
            {
                "Code": "110900",
                "Error": "xx",
                "Position": "xx",
                "Value": ""
            },
            {
                "Code": "110900",
                "Error": "xx",
                "Position": "xx",
                "Value": ""
            },
            {
                "Code": "110900",
                "Error": "xx",
                "Position": "xx",
                "Value": ""
            },
            {
                "Code": "110902",
                "Error": "xx",
                "Position": "xx",
                "Value": ""
            },
            {
                "Code": "110900",
                "Error": "xx",
                "Position": "xx",
                "Value": ""
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I need it to parse to an Angular object, so I created a couple classes:

```
export class Body{
    public ErrorsContent: ErrorsContent;
}

class ErrorsContent{
    public FunctionalError: FunctionalError;
}

class FunctionalError{
    public Code: any;
    public Error: any;
    public Position: any;
    public Value: any;
}
```

But this does not work fine when I have more than one `FuntionalError`.

> How can I set the `FuntionalError` class so that I can have more than
>   one error without being a class itself?

Any advice is welcome! Thanks.

Comment: The answer below is right, but I would also suggest you to 1) send your number values like `Code` as numbers and not as strings, 2) don't use the `: any` type. Give it the right one → In your case `string` or if you follow tip 1) also `number`

Comment: Use online helpers like http://www.jsontots.com/ to convert server responses to ts classes and avoid errors.

Comment: @MauriceNino +1 also properties name should start with lower case so for example `Code` should be `code` in classes as well as from server response

Comment: Thanks for the advices, but I receive the JSON from a remote server so I have nothing to do with that :) @MauriceNino

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your `ErrorsContent` class to

```
class ErrorsContent{
    public FunctionalError: FunctionalError[];//it should be array 
}
```

Comment: What if the JSON comes with one `FuntionalError` and it is not inside `[ ]`?

Comment: @Iñigo i will not suggest you to do that there must be consistent format.For example you execute a `foreach` and you get and `object` instead of `array` your code will break

Answer (score 3):

`FunctionalError` is an `array`. You are declaring it as a `object`.

Use

```
class ErrorsContent {
    public FunctionalError: FunctionalError[];
}
```

instead of

```
class ErrorsContent {
    public FunctionalError: FunctionalError;
}
```

You can use any online tool to convert server JSON response to TS classes. Ex: [jsontots](http://www.jsontots.com/), [json2ts](http://www.json2ts.com) etc.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
class ErrorsContent{
    public FunctionalError: Array<FunctionalError>;
}
```